# Every "Hot Network Post" and Featured post link icon just changed to the 3D Printing stack icon

Tags: bug, status-completed

I'm not sure where the best place to report site bugs is, but this is currently happening:

[image]

Comment: This 3D printing craze is getting out of hand!

Comment: Thank you for reporting this! For the future, bugs which affect the entire network rather than a single site can be reported on [meta.se]. You'll find updates on the bug's status [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287844/244929).

Comment: How come when I make photocopies of my butt and leave then around the office it's funny, but when I do 3D prints and leave them around it's perverted?

Comment: I had to read your title about 4-5 times to understand what you were saying...

Comment: Is this still happening? I'm not seeing it at this precise moment — since I'm on MacOSX/Safari, if you're still seeing it, that may indicate it's a platform-sensitive bug.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Not that I can see.  I'm on a different computer now but still on Chrome and it appears to no longer be an issue.

Comment: @LegendaryDude a [fairly quick fix](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/287848/311001) was announced on meta. (Since then, though, some different quirky behaviors have been noted w.r.t. the HNQ icons.)